# Difference of images in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, difference

I have two images to fuse. Images are
[A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xz68.gif)
[B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXshk.gif)

I have fused them and got this image  [fused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eKas.png)
Now I want difference between fused image F and the image B.
I have execute the code, but not getting desirable results

I am getting this image ->  [difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvrUR.png)  [normalized difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeBPz.png),
But I want this -> [Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIohS.png)

Values of difference image are normalized to the range of 0 to 1.

The code used is

```
difference=F-B;
figure,imshow(difference);
normImage = mat2gray(difference);
figure,imshow(normImage);
```

Please anyone help. Thank you.

Comment: How do you fuse the images? Based on the images you posted, you're subtracting uint8 images, so all of the negative values are clamped to 0.

Comment: I have two source images, which are partially blurred. The blur part in one image is clear in the other image and vice-versa. Then the image fusion based technique is applied, and the fused image is generated. Fused image is the all-in-focus image.

Comment: Okay, it's fine if you don't want to tell me. So what we've got is two images, one a uint8 3-channel image that's 214x214x3 and you're subtracting a uint8 1-channel image that's 512x512 that, even if you could subtract those two arrays from each other, you would lose data since, as I said above, you can't represent negative values in the array types you've chosen. I don't see how that's going to work.

Comment: Sir, I have told you above, how I fuse it. But the process of technique used to fuse  is too long, so I have just gave overview. Sir, one thing to note is images are 1-channel image only.  There is no RGB image.

Comment: And also, All images are of same size 512*512. If sizes are different, fusion process will not happened.

Comment: You've told me nothing about the fusion process that would give me any new information about your inputs, but as I said, that's fine. Now, my only source of data to help you with your problem is what you have posted in your question. As you say, trying to subtract a 512x512x1 array from a 214x214x3 array will fail, but that is what you posted in your question. So as not to distract you, I'm going to ask the important bit in the next comment.

Comment: Subtracting unsigned integer images gives you an unsigned integer image. The negative values are clamped to 0 in MATLAB. You need to cast the images to doubles first. Use `im2double`. Then when you display, make sure to show the proper range of intensities, for example with `imshow(img,[])` to get the minimum value in the image mapped to black and the maximum to white.

Comment: Are the two images `F` and `B`, both of type `uint8`? If so, then your results will not be what you expect.

Comment: @beaker, Sir as I said, all images are of equal size 512 *512. There is no image of 214*214*3. All images are grayscale images i.e 1-channel image. There is no 3-channel image. YEs Sir, A, B, F all three are uint8 type. All three are 512*512*1

Comment: In that case, it would be *extremely* helpful if you would post those images to your question, because that is not what you have right now. *If* your fusion process is correct, then casting your images to doubles and rescaling will give you your desired result. However, I'm a bit concerned that you've also used unsigned integers to fuse the images and that those results are not valid, either.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Sir I have used im2double but still getting same result as posted in "required" tag.

Comment: @beaker Sir, I have posted all the source images and fused image. What else I should post? Either you want more code (code for fusion process) ? 
As I have taken the code from github. So if you want link, I can provide it, but to post someone's else code is against the rules. Should I share link of github or any paper for reference?

Comment: That is precisely the problem. The source images and fused image that you posted are different sizes.

Comment: @beaker Sir I have added all the images of same size now. Please check it. The image under the "required" tag is a screenshot taken from paper so that I can show you what type of image I want. If you want to see those images in paper, I can share a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using:

```matlab
R = mat2gray(im2double(F)-im2double(B));
```

My result is:

[image]

---

To see why conversion to double is important, look at an area of the image where `B(y,x) > F(y,x)`, such as `(343, 280)` in your sample images.

```
>> F(343,280)
ans = 32
>> B(343,280)
ans = 107
```

Mathematically, we'd expect 32-107 to equal -75, but:

```
>> F(343,280) - B(343,280)
ans = 0
```

This is because both `F` and `B` are arrays of `uint8`:

```
>> class(F)
ans = uint8
>> class(B)
ans = uint8
```

As an unsigned integer, uint8 can't take a negative value, so any attempt to assign a negative value to a uint8 variable results in 0. Since both operands are uint8, the result is uint8. Trying to cast that value to a double after it has already been clamped to be with in the range of 0-255 would simply result in a double variable with a value of 0. (The same thing also happens at the upper end of the range. Try `uint8(444)`.)

Casting `F` and `B` to a signed type (one big enough to the range -max to +max, or -255 to 255 in this case) will take care of the math problem:

```
>> int16(F(343,280)) - int16(B(343,280))
ans = -75
```

For images, though, casting to `double` feels more natural and gives you more precision than integers when you're doing calculations and rescaling. Plus, there's this handy `im2double` function we can use that not only casts the array to doubles, but rescales everything to be between 0 and 1:

```
>> Fd = im2double(F);
>> Fd(343,280)
ans = 0.1255   % 32.0/255.0

>> Bd = im2double(B);
>> Bd(343,280)
ans = 0.4196   % 107.0/255.0
```

But now when we try to subtract the two, we actually get a negative value as expected:

```
>> Fd(343,280) - Bd(343,280)
ans = -0.2941  % -75.0/255.0
```

So, `im2double(F)-im2double(B)` gives us double values between -1.0 and 1.0. `mat2gray` takes care of scaling those values back to a range of 0.0 to 1.0 for display.

---

Note: I chose the coordinates (343,280) very carefully because that's where F-B is most negative. If you're curious about how the conversion happens and what values get scaled to what, you can also have a look at (53,266).

Comment: Sir, Thank you so much. It works. Actually I first find out the difference then I write im2double(difference). But sir, why does this matter. You take the difference by using im2double, and I use im2double at the result of the difference.

Comment: Sir nice explanation. I will do it at my end also. Thank you.